# Spheres and skew lines

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

***G*** is a given sphere in the space. For any line *e* that has no common point with ***G***, define the line *f* as the conjugate of *e* with respect to ***G*** if *f* joins the points of tangency on the two planes tangent to ***G*** passing through *e*. Show that two lines of the space passing ***G*** are skew if and only if their conjugates  with respect to ***G*** are skew.

Comment: And now where is your problem with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will prove that if two lines $a$ and $b$ are coplanar, then their conjugate lines $a'$ and $b'$ are coplanar too. This is only a first step in your proof, I'll leave to you the rest.

Let $O$ be the center of sphere $\boldsymbol{G}$ and $r$ its radius. First of all observe that the conjugate $a'$ of a line $a$ lies in the plane through $O$ and perpendicular to $a$. If $A$ is the projection of $O$ on $a$, then $a'$ is perpendicular to $OA$ and the intersection between $OA$ and and $a'$ is the point $A'$ such that 
$$OA'=r^2/OA.$$

Suppose now that line $a$ lies on a plane $\sigma$ and let $H$ be the projection of $O$ onto $\sigma$. By the theorem of three perpendiculars, the projection of $H$ on $a$ is the same as the projection $A$ of $O$ on $a$. Line $a'$ (the conjugate of $a$) lies on plane $OHA$ and intersects line $OH$ at a point $K$. Triangles $OAH$ and $OA'K$ are similar, so we get:
$$
OK={OA'\cdot OA\over OH}={r^2\over OH}.
$$

This result does not depend on the position of $a$ on $\sigma$: it follows that the conjugates of lines lying on $\sigma$ all pass through the same point $K$, belonging to the perpendicular line from $O$ to $\sigma$ and whose distance from $O$ is given by the above equation.